# is it posible to add new value to ehcache in spring?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to use ehcache in my java project, it's new for me.

now i am using ehcache for retrieving area list, and my project adding new area , that time i am using @TriggersRemove functionality for once clear the cache and then reload it.

ex: i have retrive 10 areas and using ehcache , and i adding one more area that time i clear the cache and reload it.

is any other options for avoiding the data reload in cache.

my code:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="retrieveAreas")
public List<AreaBO> retrieveAreas(){

      //some code here
}

@TriggersRemove(cacheName="retrieveAreas", removeAll=true)
public long addArea(AreaBO areaBO) throws UserServiceException{

      // some codes here

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are reloading the cache. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: hai geoand,  i want to display the new added area, so i load cache again , is it possible for avoiding reload cache, and add new value to cache?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the annotation from EhCache. If you where to switch to the caching annotations provided by [Spring](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/09/spring-31-caching-and-ehcache.html) since version 3.1 your code would be:

```
@Cacheable(value="retrieveAreas")
public List<AreaBO> retrieveAreas(){

      //some code here
}

@CachePut(value="retrieveAreas")
public long addArea(AreaBO areaBO) throws UserServiceException{

      // some codes here

}
```

The difference as you can see is in the @CachePut annotation that adds the return value of the method to the cache specified.
I am not aware of a corresponding annotation in EHCache